Chrome Extension как мне загрузить на сайт css в приоритете над css который подгрузил сайт
Я хочу загрузить css на сайт который будет менять некоторые элементы для этого я использую манифест
"content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["./scripts/material.js", "./scripts/content.js"],
    "css": ["./css/test.css"],
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
}],

css:
body {
    background-color: yellow;
}

Но это работает исключительно на сайтах где нету css который загрузил сайт. Я хотел бы узнать можно ли как то загрузить test.css в приоритете над css который подгрузил сайт?

Если твой css будет "расположен ниже" другого css - принцип каскадности даст тебе преимущество перед другим css. При учете, как минимум, равнозначности селекторов.

Я вообще не понимаю куда он добавляется. В html нету строки с линком. Если я удаляю css сайта то олько после этого налаживается мой css

@Lotti в html и тэга 